# Barcode Scanner plugin failing when building in Adobe Build using Phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, barcode-scanner, phonegap

I'm having a massive amount of trouble trying to get the barcode-scanner plugin from [this GitHub page](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) to build in Adobe Build.  To be clear, the scanner works great itself when testing the app. But when I build the app using Adobe Build, I get an error in the log file that my cordova-android version isn't where it should be.  This is the output from the log file:

> Fetching plugin "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner@~7.1.0" via npm
>
> Installing "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" at "7.1.1" for android
>
> Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version.
> cordova-android: 6.1.2, failed version requirement: >=6.3.0
>
> Skipping 'phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner' for android

I've been looking for hours for ways to update the cordova-android version for my project. I've tried starting new projects with the newest Phonegap CLI. And I am now at a loss for how to proceed.  Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of downgrading the plugin, upgrade your Phonegap CLI version so it uses a newer cordova-android. You will need to use Phonegap CLI 7.1.0 or newer, you can set it by adding this to your config.xml

`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.1.0" />`

Comment: I had already tried this; however, this broke the other installed plugins.  It was far easier to point to a stable version that supports my CLI than trying to reinstall every single plugin.

Comment: Strange, as far as I know, CLI 7.1.0 doesn't break any plugin, but if 7.1.0 breaks your plugins, then don't try 8.0.0 as it uses cordova-android 7.1.0, which has a lot of incompatibilities with plugins. Anyway, downgrading is always a bad option and just a temporary fix, sooner or later Adobe will bump the min version and deprecate it and you will have to update even if it break things, so the sooner you fix the problems the better.

Comment: I will try that and let you know the results, jcesarmobile. Thank you!

Comment: I've undone my acceptance of my own answer and placed you as the best answer and +1 for your help.  This is a much better solution. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else goes through the h-e-double hockey sticks I just went through, I changed the version of the plugin for the Barcode Scanner in the app's main `config.xml` to be an older version (6.0.0) and it works with the built `apk` from Adobe Build.

This is what my line read as when it was installed:

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="~7.0.1" />
```

And I changed it to:

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="6.0.0" />
```

Comment: Accept your answer to reduce the number of unanswered questions :)